# Jquery animate + if css position

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate, position

I am actualy trying to check the top position of a div element which i am moving with a jquery animate function.

```
$('#nss .nss-pager-up').click(function() {
    $('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').animate({
        top: '+=55'
    }, 300, function() {
        if($('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').css('top') == '55') {
            alert('hey');
        }
 });
});
```

Someone got an idea why this wont work?

Comment: Have you inspected the value of the css property top?  It could be '55px'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned value contains unit, pixel:

```
if ( $('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').css('top') == '55px' ) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cY5vw/

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the "top" style hasn't been set.

I would go for the following instead

```
$('#nss .nss-pager-up').click(function() {
    $('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').animate({
        top: $(this).position().top + 55
 }, 300, function() {
        if($('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').css('top') == '55') {
            alert('hey');
        }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use position()

http://jsfiddle.net/ySYWB/1/

```
$('#nss .nss-pager-up').click(function() {
    $('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').animate({
        top: '+=50'
    }, 300, function() {
    if($('.nss-stream-inner-wrap').position().top > 55) {
        alert('hey');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the > is usually safer, but you can stick to ==